# Filtering a Flux based upon the contents of the Flux, without blocking

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactive

Requirement: given the list of Servers in a Flux, return the LOCAL server if it is present, OR return the DEV servers if the LOCAL server is not present, and must be done in a non-blocking way.

I don't know how to do that with the Flux.filter method since it only allows you to examine one element at a time, and to perform that filtering you have to know what is in the whole list ahead of time.  This was easy with blocking code as I simply iterated over the entire list ahead of time to determine if it had LOCAL or DEV instances, etc.  Not sure how to do this with a Flux though.

Server Class:

```
class Server {
    public String environment;
    public String hostName;
    public Server(String environment, String hostName) {
        this.environment = environment;
        this.hostName = hostName;
    }
}
```

Filter Method:

```
public Flux<Server> filterServersLocalOrDev(Flux<Server> serverFlux) {
    
    Flux<Server> filteredServers = // do filtering here..how to?
    
    return filteredServers;
}
```

Demo calling code:

```
Server server1 = new Server("DEV", "dev1.somecompany.com");
Server server2 = new Server("TEST", "test1.somecompany.com");
Server server3 = new Server("DEV", "dev2.somecompany.com");
Server server4 = new Server("LOCAL", "localhost");

Flux<Server> serverFlux = Flux.just(server1, server2, server3, server4);
Flux<Server> filteredServerFlux = filterServersLocalOrDev(serverFlux);
    
// filteredServerFlux should only contain LOCAL if it is 
// present OR the two DEV servers if there is no LOCAL
```

Comment: if you need to treat them as a single collection of objects for filtering, you can instead use a `Mono<List<Server>>`.

Comment: You could use `collectList` or `collectMap` to buffer elements and then `flatMapIterable` to transform back to `Flux`

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter and switchIfEmpty. It will return Local servers if present otherwise returns dev servers like this

```
 public Flux<Server> filterServersLocalOrDev(Flux<Server> serverFlux) {

        Flux<Server> filteredServers = serverFlux
                .filter(s -> "LOCAL".equals(s.environment))
                .switchIfEmpty(serverFlux.filter(s -> "DEV".equals(s.environment)));

        return filteredServers;
    }
```